# Need to extract text with REGEXP_SUBSTR - cannot find the right combination

Tags: oracle, netsuite

Here is an example of my text- I am trying to get TEXTPART3 AS THE ANSWER:

TEXTPART1 : TEXTPART2: TEXTPART3 - TEXTPART4

I used TRIM(LEADING ':' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR('textstatementhere', ':.+?-')) - but it is not accounting for the two ":" and the "-" in the text statement  I get ' TEXTPART2: TEXTPART3 -'

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does it have to be "with REGEXP_SUBSTR"? The method by which you solve a problem is generally not part of the problem requirements. Your problem has a much more efficient solution **without** regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Leverage the REGEXP_SUBSTR Function to Do All of Your Work**

Use a subexpression, `(\w)`, and reference it:

```
WITH exmple AS (
    SELECT
        'TEXTPART1 : TEXTPART2: TEXTPART3 - TEXTPART4' txt
    FROM
        dual
)
SELECT
    txt,
    regexp_substr(txt, ': (\w*) -', 1, 1, NULL,
                  1)
FROM
    exmple;
```

I see that you used `.`, in lieu of `\w`. Because you chose the meta-character,`.` (which represents all characters except new line (though that can be included if "n" is set as a pattern matching modifier)), the second colon is thrown in to the matching set.

What does TEXTPART3 include?

Perhaps the meta-character, `\w`, (which stands for alphanumeric or underscore (_) character), is not what you need.

You could replace it with a non-matching character list to avoid the problems with `.`:

`[^:]`.

This approach would look like this:

`REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, ': ([^:]*) -',1,1,NULL,1)`

Lastly, with the quantiifier associated with this subexpression, I used `*` which means zero or more matches. I assumed that there would be instances where there could be zero matches for this TEXTPART3. If this is not the case, we can use `+`.

Comment: There is at least one more assumption you didn't mention: the TEXTPART2 string doesn't contain a dash preceded by a space. Something like this input: ABC : DEF - GEH : TEXTPART3 - TEXTPART4. Perhaps this pattern is not possible in the data, but the OP didn't specifically exclude it.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I did assume.

Comment: Thanks everyone REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, ': ([^:]*) -',1,1,NULL,1) solved my problem..

Answer (score 1):

The problem has a more efficient solution using only standard string functions:

```
with
  sample_input (str) as (
    select 'TEXTPART1 : TEXTPART2: TEXTPART3 - TEXTPART4' from dual
  )
select substr(str, pos, instr(str, '-', pos) - pos - 1) as text_part_3
from   (select str, instr(str, ':', 1, 2) + 2 as pos from sample_input)
;


TEXT_PART_3
-----------
TEXTPART3
```